# Shoe Animation Issue

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I am very new to blender. I made a model of my shoe, I now want to practise animating. I have added an Armature with weight, however my layers are not attached and do not move as a single unit. I have tried to join the layers but I have been unsuccessful.

Please could someone help me solve this issue? Thanks

[Rigged Shoe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxMTR.png)

[image: Issues with rigged shoe]

Comment: The laces, sole and other thing that dont follow along with the bone is because those object did not have weight assigned to the bone yet. Make sure to assign weight painting to those object.

Comment: Okay, I have very little knowledge on weight painting. I think I will look into this and see if I can figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Or if you want the quickest way, try to join all of the object into 1 object. And try to parenting it with Automatic Weight.

Comment: I did try joining them but im not sure if I performed the action correctly. What would be the best way to do this?